# verifying RS256 JWT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jwt, key

I'm new to JWT and I'm having trouble with verifying the JWT when using the RS256 algorithm. I get error 403 every single time I try to verify the token, but I don't understand why. I'm certain I'm using the right key-files. I even tried writing :
jwt.verify(publicKey, publicKey) and even with that I got error 403! Aren't they supposed to match each other exactly? What exactly is jwt.verify() doing? Is it checking if the first value is equal to the second value? Is it decoding the key?

This is how I sign the token:

```
 import fs from 'fs'

 const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private.pem', 'utf8')

 const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, {
        algorithm: 'RS256',
        expiresIn: '1h'
      })
```

And this is how I verify the token:

```
import createError from 'http-errors'

const authorize = (req, res, next) => {
const authorization = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./public.pem', 'utf8')

try {
  const payload = jwt.verify(authorization[1], publicKey)
  next()

} catch (err) {
   next(createError(403))
 }
}
```

Comment: With verification you check if the signature (an encrypted hash) is identical to a hash that you create during verification. I recommend to read some basis [here](https://jwt.io/introduction). Regarding your problem, do a `console.log(authorization[1])` before the call to `jwt.verify(...` and show the result here.

Comment: @jps I ran the token through the debugger in https://jwt.io/ and got "Invalid signature". I just created the token so I'm sure that it's not expired. I created the pem-files through "openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048" in terminal so it should be valid. What could be the reason for a signature to be invalid?

Comment: I guess you didn't  provide the puplic key to jwt.io. Without the puplic key it can't verify the signature. I still would like to see the exact output as requested in my first comment.

Comment: this is what I get when i console.log(authorization[1]):
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0VXNlcjVAdGVzdGVtYWlsLmNvbSIsInhfcGVybWlzc2lvbl9sZXZlbCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI5MzgzMTE4LCJleHAiOjE2MjkzODY3MTh9.Bbqly0mI_YbHdj3IZ1-63CLvgc4nfesrGS2a-bAhXBcRXdVdlJeudiFpAKybpVfjiLJe97kleaOhOSurqNcqlIKGke-bHn1hBdIhZ_PV8bDzGkq5P1K0LUZhL3z9k33Mz5vl05maKAvSXhE6mLnFfU0_d7JNZrgFvXUlzwR7cXBwE4ztQ1SSAc7UcAsf9IkgPaM0bijbsSXW7ieBj4KS1oFVFFXzMzpmtlbZsqIIs0I_HrBTJAb7o8IO2AC-8V4HzejRTshbc-9n6JvuLhk9r2N_zLOMRzFipBhDsBL7q2G23UwbFOvSpYNkJyA-1Vq0Ar_uFtSSUcjJWDCfM_fEFQ

Comment: the token looks fine. Based on the given nformation I can't tell you what's wrong. Maybe something wrong with key?